# "Open" port is not really open

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port

I used the following command to open port 2022 in Ubuntu:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2022 -j ACCEPT
```

But if I start a web server on port 2022 it is not reachable.

If I run the command to see open ports:

```
sudo iptables -vnL
```

The output starts with

[image]

Now, ports that show up there like 3000 or 4000 work, but 2022 does not.

What's going on and how can I enable port 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order matters. Your entry for 2022 in the iptables is behind `DROP`, so `DROP` is matched first and your `ACCEPT` entry is never reached.

You need to Insert instead of Append (`-I` instead of `-A`).

Answer (score 0):

*Open* port is a port that the packet filter doesn't block.
In order for this port to be reachable something has to bind to it, and, in the TCP case, start to *listen* on it.

You can check whether something's doing it with `ss -nl` or `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`.